# Deploying an Web Application built using Asp.Net,C# and Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, deployment

I have developed a **simple Web Application using Asp.Net, C# and SQL Server 2008 R2**.
The Application is intended to capture the Employee Details and storing the same in Database and retrieving them when needed.
Its working fine with me.

Now my Question is the Deployment of it in the Local Machine.
Is IIS compulsarily needed for me to do this, or else something else can do the same.

Please **`provide with some basic guidelines for deployment`**, as I am a beginner oly. :(
I haven't found an understandable, basic one in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need iss on your local machine to deploy the application. Install it first then follow these steps written in these links..

http://www.brainbrushups.com/2013/05/how-to-deploy-or-publish-aspnet-website.html

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-to-iis-as-a-test-environment-5-of-12

http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource7-Deploying-aspnet-applications-on-IIS-web-server.aspx